# Trying to create a query function for PDO

Tags: php, pdo

As I am writing a script, I am typing $db->prepare()'s and $stmt->bindParam()'s constantly. I am looking for a way to consolidate it all in a function. This is what I have so far.

```
$sql = "SELECT (name, email) FROM users WHERE VALUES (:name, :email)"
$values = array(':name' => 'my_name', ':email' => 'blahblah@example.com', );

    function db_query($sql, $values) {
    global $db; //Database object

        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

        foreach($values as $placeholder => $value) {
            $stmt->bindParam($placeholder, $value);

        }

        $stmt->execute();

        $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        return $result;
      }
```

Would this be sufficient for most queries? Is this a secure way to do this?

I just want the query to run and return whatever it returns (NULL, values, error, etc...).

Thanks.

Comment: couldn't you replace that foreach loop with `$stmt->execute($values);`?

Comment: It should be sufficient, as long as it works. Write a few Test Cases for each items you will be doing, fetching / inserting / deleting / updating. I tend to have the "query" be an actual query, and write a separate function for fetching IE `fetchAll` `fetchOne`, but I also just extend the PDO class with my own wrapper, so I don't have to mess with the global business. :) Best way to see if it is sufficient and works...is to test it and see.

Comment: +1 for the question being of extremely rare kind here.

Comment: Brad, is fetch and fetchall the only two ways to get the results from a query? Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Your code will not work as expected because `bindParam()` binds the placeholder name (first argument) to the variable *reference* present in the second argument.

Using your example, this would result in all parameters set to `blahblah@example.com` as it is the last `$value` in the loop.

As mentioned in the comments, simply use `$stmt->execute($values)`. See http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

If you really want to continue with your loop, use `PDOStatement::bindValue()` instead.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Is the $result variable "correct" in the sense that it will return whatever the query sends back regardless of SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE, etc.. Using mysql functions I did this:

$result = mysql_query($query);

Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Brandon Given the information in my answer, I'd argue against creating this wrapper function at all.

Comment: Ok. Is there a "best practices" way to remove tons of redundant PDO code? I am actually looking at Drupal's db_query as inspiration. A lot of my code is just prepare()'s and execute()'s all over the place. Thanks.